# Getting multiple error messages with my python script

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, path, python-3.6

I have a python script where I'm trying to read all .txt files in a directory and determine if they return True or False for any conditions that are in my script. I'm getting a few error messages that I have listed below. I want the script to read in .txt files that contain text formatted in .json format. Then I want the script to determine if the .txt file matches any of the statements in my code below. I then want to output the result to a csv file. Your help is very much appreciated! The second error messages does not make any sense since there are .txt files in .json format in the directory that I specify in the path.

```
File "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/best_version_of_vt_checker.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(vt_result_check(path))
  File "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/best_version_of_vt_checker.py", line 10, in vt_result_check
    with open(filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.2500.c.dynadns.eu.txt'

import os
import json

path=r'./output/'


def vt_result_check(path):
    vt_result = False
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

        # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
        # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
        # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
        # Look for any positive detected URLs
        sample_types = ('detected_referrer_samples', 'detected_communicating_samples',
                        'detected_downloaded_samples', 'detected_urls')
        vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types
                                                 for sample in vt_data.get(sample_type, []))

        # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Dr.Web category') == "known infection source"

        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
        threats = ("elevated exposure", "phishing and other frauds", "suspicious content")
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category') in threats

    return vt_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(vt_result_check(path))
    with open(csvpath, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer.writerow([vt_result_check()])
```

**Error messages again***

```
File "C:/Users/bwerner/Documents/3pm_reporter.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(vt_result_check(path))
  File "C:/Users/bwerner/Documents/3pm_reporter.py", line 11, in vt_result_check
    vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)
  File "C:\Users\bwerner\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\bwerner\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\bwerner\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\bwerner\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using os.listdir to get all of the files in the folder `output`. However when you try to open them, you are only using the filename, without the `output` folder. You need to include the path along with the filename.

Replace the line `with open(filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:` with this line: `with open(path+filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:`

This combines the path and the filename, so that it will correctly locate the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's been running for the last few minutes so I don't know what the output is since it's not printing anything to the console. I would like to print the output to a csv. The code I have is:     
with open(csvpath, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer.writerow([vt_result_check()])

Is this right? I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: @bedford your question was about fixing that error. If you have another question, please post it as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If my answer above solved the question that you posted, please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: I actually got the same error again as the script eventually failed. I included the error messages above.

Comment: @bedford that is a different error message, and it appears to be because the JSON file is invalid. Again, please ask a new question if you are having more issues.